# Calculation performance scipy weibull min fit vs Matlab wblfit

Tags: python, matlab, curve-fitting, weibull, scipy.stats

Playing around with fitting data to Weibull distributions, using Matlab `wblrnd` and `wblfit` functions, and Python `scipy.stats.weibull_min.fit` function, I found that Matlab outperforms Python by almost 2 orders of magnitude. I am looking for some help to improve the performance of the Python code.

**The problem:**

While converting Matlab code to Python, I came across the following code:

```
weibull_parameters = zeros(10000, 2)
for i = 1:10000
    data = sort(wblrnd(alpha, beta, 1, 24))
    [weibull_parameters(i, :), ~] = wblfit(data, confidence_interval, censoring_array)
end
```

This code generates 24 random numbers from a Weibull distribution and then fits the resulting data vector again to a Weibull distribution.

In Python I translated this to:

```
from scipy.stats import weibull_min
import numpy as np


data = np.sort(alpha * np.random.default_rng().weibull(beta, (10000, 24)))

weibull_parameters = np.zeros((10000, 2))
for idx, row in enumerate(data):
    weibull_parameters[idx, :] = weibull_min.fit(row, floc=0)[2::-2]
```

Here I generate the full random data in one go and then iterate over the rows to get the corresponding Weibull parameters using the weibull_min.fit function. The slicing at the end is to select only the scale and shape parameters in the output and put them in the correct order.

The main problem I encountered is that the calculation performance in Python is terrible. Matlab runs this code in a few seconds, however for Python it takes 1-1.5 seconds per 100 iterations (on my laptop), so the difference in performance is almost 2 orders of magnitude.

Is there a way that I can improve the performance in Python? Is is possible to vectorize the fitting calculation? I couldn't find anything online on this topic unfortunately.

> Note 1: Matlab allows the user to specify a confidence interval in the wblfit function however for Python I couldn't find a way to include that, so I ignored that.

> Note 2: The only option I could find to include censoring was using the [surpyval package](https://surpyval.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), however the performance was even more dreadful (about 10 seconds per 100 iterations)

Answer (score 2):

Python is not know for being the fastest language out there. There are things you can do to speed it up but you will find there is a balance between accuracy and speed.

As for ways to fit a Weibull distribution, there are several packages to do this. The packages [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.weibull_min.html), [surpyval](https://surpyval.readthedocs.io/en/latest/applications.html), [lifelines](https://lifelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Survival%20analysis%20with%20lifelines.html?highlight=weibullfitter), and [reliability](https://reliability.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) will all fit complete data. The last 3 will also handle censored data which scipy will not.

I'm the author of reliability, so I'll present you an example using this package:

```
from reliability.Distributions import Weibull_Distribution
from reliability.Fitters import Fit_Weibull_2P
import time
import numpy as np

rows=100
samples = 24
data_array = np.empty((rows,samples))
true_parameters = np.empty((rows,2))
for i in range(rows):
    alpha = np.random.randint(low=1,high=999) + np.random.rand() #alpha between 1 and 1000
    beta = np.random.randint(low=1,high=10) - np.random.rand()/2 #beta between 0.5 and 10
    true_parameters[i][0] = alpha
    true_parameters[i][1] = beta
    dist = Weibull_Distribution(alpha=alpha,beta=beta)
    data_array[i]=dist.random_samples(samples)

start_time = time.time()
parameters = np.empty((rows,2))
for i in range(rows):
    fit = Fit_Weibull_2P(failures=data_array[i],show_probability_plot=False,print_results=False)
    parameters[i][0] = fit.alpha
    parameters[i][1] = fit.beta

runtime = time.time()-start_time
# np.set_printoptions(suppress=True) #supresses the scientific notation used by numpy
# print('True parameters:')
# print(true_parameters)
# print('Fitted parameters:')
# print(parameters)
print('Runtime:',runtime,'seconds')
print('Runtime per iteration:',runtime/rows,'seconds')
```

When I run this it gives:

```
Runtime: 3.378781318664551 seconds
Runtime per iteration: 0.033787813186645504 seconds
```

Based on the times you quoted in your question, this is about twice as slow as scipy but only one third of the time taken by surpyval.

I hope this helps to show you a different way to do the same thing, but I understand it probably isn't the performance improvement you are seeking. The only way you will get a big performance improvement is to use least squares estimation in pure python, perhaps accelerated using numba. Such an approach will likely give you results that are inferior to MLE, but as I said earlier, there is a balance between speed and accuracy, as well as between speed and coding convenience.

Comment: Thanks for showing me the Reliability package, I indeed didn't know about it. Unfortunately I cannot move away from using MLE, since that is the industry standard. I am still shocked that MATLAB is able to execute the fitting so fast. Perhaps it does a lot of parallelization/vectorization under the hood. 

Now, while the results you show indicate at least a more favorable approach to implement censoring, the performance is still too slow. Because we need to run the fitting part 4 times in our code, so that would mean people are waiting for 20 minutes for the code to finish. Maybe Numba helps

Comment: If you need to use MLE then numba won't be able to help you (not unless you are willing to dig into the source code of autograd). Does your dataset contain large amounts of repeated values? If so then you may find lifelines faster.